# Como posso validar um enum usando FluentValidator?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Estou criando uma classe de validação no `c#` usando `FluentValidation` para validar que minha propriedade `Type` de minha classe `Account` seja do tipo `AccountType` que é meu `enum`.

Como seria a implementação correta disto?

```
 RuleFor (account => account.Type)
             .IsInEnum (....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você chegou bem próximo da solução,você pode usar o [Must](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) para verificar o tipo de seus campos ou campara-los com outros campos o no seu caso com um `enum`,

Para saber se o tipo de um campo é igual a um determinado tipo você primeiro precisar capturar o tipo do campo com o `GetType()`.

```
RuleFor(x => x).Must(p => p.Type.GetType().IsEnum);
```

O `IsEnum`, já faz sua verificação que você precisa, o Fluent Validation tem uma condição de erro para ser disparado quando o resultado for `TRUE`, então se você quer que seja lançado um erro quando sua propriedade seja diferente de IsEnum então use uma negação.

```
RuleFor(x => x).Must(p => !p.Type.GetType().IsEnum);
```

Para uma verificação em uma classe cliente ficaria assim.

```
using FluentValidation;
using System;

namespace TesteDryIoC.Generic.Validacoes
{
    public class ClienteValidator : AbstractValidator<Cliente>
    {
        public ClienteValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x).Must(p => p.Type == MeusEnuns.Numero);
            RuleFor(x => x).Must(p => p.Type.GetType().IsEnum);
        }
    }
}
```

No `RoleFor`, eu estou acessando minha classe cliente e passando para o Must todas as suas propriedades, você poder fazer varias verificação assim ou até mesmo chamar um método mais robusto devolvendo um `bool` com o resultado da validação.